# Does this limit converge?

Tags: limits

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln(1+\sin(2x))}{x} $$

I think it doesn't converge, but don't know how to prove it.

Comment: A small remark: a sequence or function may *converge* (at a point), but a limit does not. It *exists*, or does not exist.

Comment: the searched limit doesn't exist,

Comment: The quantity you are looking at is not even well-defined: when $\sin 2x=-1$ (which happens a lot: consider $x=n\pi+\frac{3\pi}{4}$ for some integer $n$), then it would involve $\log 0$, which is not defined. (That, assuming the common interpretation that $x$ refers to a real-valued number. Do you mean to impose any restriction on $x$, e.g. that it's an integer?)

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That's not very helpful... what is the OP supposed to derive or understand from your comment?

Comment: Perhaps you mean the limit as $x$ tends to $0$? That would be more interesting

Answer (score 3):

The numerator in
$$
\frac{\ln(1+\sin(2x))}x
$$
is not defined for all real numbers: it doesn't exist when $\sin(2x)=-1$, that is when $2x=\frac{3\pi}2+2k\pi$, or $$x=\frac{3\pi}4+k\pi.$$

Even if we remove those points from the domain of the function, the limit doesn't exist. When $x=\frac12\,\arcsin(-1+e^{-cn})+n\pi$, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{\ln(1+\sin(2x))}x&=\frac{\ln(1+\sin(\arcsin(-1+e^{-cn})+2n\pi))}{\frac12\,\arcsin(-1+e^{-cn})+n\pi}=\frac{\ln(e^{-cn}))}{\frac12\,\arcsin(-1+e^{-cn})+n\pi}\\ \ \\
&=\frac{-cn}{\frac12\,\arcsin(-1+e^{-cn})+n\pi}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}-\frac c\pi.
\end{align}
We can do this for any $c>0$, so the limit does not exist.

If instead we use $\frac12\,\arcsin(-1+e^{-cn^2})+n\pi$, we can make the quotients go to $-\infty$.

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+log%281%2Bsin%282x%29%29%2Fx) can be used to get a feeling of the behavior of the function.